# Copying only the Filename of Excel files from folder with the help of sas

Tags: sql, excel, sas

Hi I need to copy the filename of xls files from one folder.

Please help how can be done

Comment: I don't fully understand what you are trying to achieve. Do you want a SAS dataset containing the names of Excel files in a specific folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using just SAS code, this will print out to the log all files that have an extension that starts with ".xls" - which includes the new versions that have extension .xlsx

You can easily modify this to save the list to a data set instead - or execute some action on each file.

```
%macro list_excel(location);
filename _dir_ "%bquote(&location.)";
data _null_;
  handle=dopen( '_dir_' );
  if handle > 0 then do;
    count=dnum(handle);
    do i=1 to count;
      memname=dread(handle,i);
      if index(memname,'.xls') then  put memname;
    end;
  end;
  rc=dclose(handle);
run;
filename _dir_ clear;
%mend;

/* example usage */
%list_excel(C:\temp\);
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume you use MS Windows.

1. Press the bottom left "Start"
   button, select "Run".
2. Type "cmd" or
   "command" (depends on windows
   version). A command line window
   opens.
3. Type "F:" or the drive letter
   where the folder is located. Type
   "cd foldername\foldername\ ...
   foldername" to locate the folder
   where the xls files are located.
4. Type "dir /w *.xls". A list of xls
   file names appears, which you can
   now copy and paste.

Comment: The full path could simply be incorporated into the `dir` command, no need to go to that folder.